# How can I make DBRefs with MongoDB Ruby Driver 2?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, database-connection, dbref, database

I have noticed, with surprise, that in the new version of MongoDB Ruby Driver, BSON::DBRef has disappeared. Given that MongoDB's website still states that the Ruby Driver supports DBRefs I imagine that only the mode of accessing DBRefs has changed. But how can I create and load DBRefs with Ruby Driver 2 (Using MongoDB 3)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not included in the 2.0 gem currently, but it's going to be added soon for backwards compatibility. Please see this [mongodb-user message](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/stolfo/14c56e81bc417257) on the topic, from one of the driver devs.